# SQLITE_BUSY on exclusively read only accesses

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

in my C++ application, using the SQLite 3.8.11 API I have multiple threads reading from the same SQLite database. Each thread opens the DB with the SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY. As far as I understand the SQLite documentation, including this page:

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

I should be able to read from the database from multiple threads as long as no write operations are happening (SHARED lock).

Still I get SQLITE_BUSY results from sqlite3_prepare_v2 statements all the time...

I have checked other topics on stack overflow similar to this problem, but in all these cases there have been at least one writer thread. I have only reader threads.

What is it that I have missed here? :)

Edit: Here is the code that opens the database

```
if(sqlite3_open_v2(filename.c_str(), &_db, sqlite_flags, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    if(_log) _log->ErrorFormat(L"Failed to open SQLite database %hs, error = %hs", filename.c_str(), sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
    return false;
}
```

I have verified in the debugger that the sqlite_flags variable is set to SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY

I have also verified that the SQLite library is compiled with thread support, the sqlite3_threadsafe() call returns 1, which should mean serialized mode. As far as I understand it, this is the safest mode for multi-threading.

Comment: Show us the code that opens the database please.  Also have a read of http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html  it might depend on how SQLite was compiled.

Comment: I've updated the post with the opening code and threadsafe mode

Comment: Do the threads share the same connection object?

Comment: No, each thread opens its own db handle